# I purchased a tank and a jet plane in Gta in story mode and I don't know how to spawn it in

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

After I completed the game and got a lot of money, I wanted to just buy some cool stuff. I ended up buying a hangar, tank, and a plane. I don't know how to spawn in the tank or the plane. Can someone help me?

Comment: With "spawn" you mean get in it and use it?

Answer (score 3):

If you go to a hangar or garage you've purchased you can press your interact button (default <kbd>E</kbd> on PC) to be presented with the vehicles you've purchased. Use this to spawn the purchased vehicle at that location.